# Deep Link is not working on Samsung mobiles(When i try to open it from Default messenger)

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, deep-linking, samsung-mobile-sdk

I have developed an android application on which i'm using deep-link to open the application and it is working perfectly on all the other device except in Samsung mobiles and that too when i try to open it via Samsung default Messenger, instead of launching the application it is redirecting me to Google play store.
Please give me solution to find out what i have missed out.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:exported="true"
                android:host="frr.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:exported="true"
                android:host="frr.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:exported="true"
                android:host="www.frr.com"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:exported="true"
                android:host="www.frr.com"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

And this is the link- https://frr.com/open.php

Comment: I got the impression from the docs that an `<intent-filter>` element may not contain more than one `<data>` element.

Comment: That is to say, every `<data>` element you provide is merged into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of deep-linking into apps on Android: App Links and URI Schemes. The configuration you provide is for App Links, which many apps on Android still do not support. In order to link out of such apps you must use a URI Scheme. To ensure the widest support you should configure your app to use both App Links and a URI Scheme.

Here is an example intent-filter for linking to an app with the URI Scheme "branchtest" via URI Scheme:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="branchtest"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I grabbed this example from a Branch demo app that supports both App Links and URI Schemes, here: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/android-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/Branch-SDK-TestBed/AndroidManifest.xml